# R Command for replacing value

Tags: r

hi just learning R and looking at how to do this.

How do i change a value of "1" in vehicle vector where it should be filled with the proper value from vendor$shop vector.   I'm trying to make a weighted adjacency matrix

Answer (score 0):

```
vehicle_vector[vehicle_vector == 1] <- new_value
```